# Unexpected error on deleting taxonomy

Tags: 8

On deleting a term or full vocabulary I'm getting this error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

I tried to delete terms but this error occurred but those were successfully deleted.

In error log I see this error:

```
 [Tue Apr 07 18:27:20.141012 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 24707:tid 140522664453888] [client 103.87.207.242:59315] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Error: Call to a member function delete() on null in govtschemes.in/modules/taxonomy_breadcrumb/taxonomy_breadcrumb.module

 on line 110 #0 [internal function]: 
taxonomy_breadcrumb_taxonomy_vocabulary_delete(Object(Drupal\\taxonomy\\Entity\\Vocabulary))\n#1 govtschemes.in/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php(403): call_user_func_array('taxonomy_breadc...', Array)\n#2 govtschemes.in/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/ConfigEntityStorage.php(347): Drupal\\Core\\Extension\\ModuleHandler->invokeAll('taxonomy_vocabu...', Array)\n#3 

govtschemes.in/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(434): Drupal\\Core\\Config\\Entity\\ConfigEntityStorage->invokeHook('delete', Object(Drupal\\taxonomy\\Entity\\Vocabulary))\n#4 govtschemes.in/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityBase.php(403): 

Drupal\\Core\\Entity\\EntityStorageBase->delete(Array)\n#5 govtschemes.in/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityDeleteFormTrait.php(122): Drupal\\Cor...\n', referer: http://www.govtschemes.in/admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/govt_department/delete?destination=/admin/structure/taxonomy
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the "taxonomy_breadcrumb" module.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I disabled it then now working fine now